# Optional explicit block parameter in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, optional-parameters, ruby-block

*As noted in the comments, the question is actually the answer.*

If the method gets a block, I want to use it further. But I also have a variant where the block isn’t needed. Can I do this in any way?

For example:

```rb
def maybe_gets_block(&blk)
  if blk
    STDERR.puts "Yay! I’ve got a block!"
    @callback = blk
  else
    STDERR.puts "I don’t have a block"
    @callback = nil
  end
end
```

Comment: The method you have shown here should work fine. If you pass a block to `maybe_gets_block`, it will be converted to a Proc and assigned to `@callback`. If you don't pass a block, `nil` will be assigned. Is anything not working with this solution?

Comment: @HolgerJust Thank you! Yes, that’s right. I don’t know why I thought it wouldn’t work—I’m nearly sure I haven’t upgraded Ruby since I last tried that. Shall I delete this question then? Or keep it for other confused people?

Comment: @Bohdan : I would keep the question. The example is well written and the comments and the answer are enlightening.

Answer (score 1):

### Using Kernel#block_given?

You're probably looking for [Kernel#block_given?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Kernel.html#method-i-block_given-3F). Generally, you'll use that in combination with [Object#yield](https://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-yield). For example, here's a snippet that will act on an optional block or proc before falling back on some other action.

```
def maybe_gets_block prc=nil
  if block_given?
    yield
  elsif prc.is_a? Proc
    prc.call
  else
    # do something else
  end
end
```

Comment: Doesn’t this require calling it like `maybe_gets_block(proc { puts "test" })`?

Comment: @Bohdan Nope. Ruby always takes an optional block. There’s no need to handle it explicitly as an argument in most cases.